# Некорректное отображение word файла в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, docx

Имеется word-файл `.docx`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подгружаю его в `RichTextBox`:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object File = pathFile;
object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
wordObject.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open(ref File, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
richTextBox1.Paste();
docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
wordObject.Quit();
```

В итоге отображается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от этих лишних линий? Пробовал менять размеры `RichTextBox`, зум, ничего не помогает.

Comment: версия дотнета какая?

Comment: @aepot, .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Проверьте, воспроизводится ли в Winforms на .NET 6, кажется вы древний контрол используете, он просто может не поддерживать то что вам нужно.

Comment: @aepot, библиотека `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` не дружит с .NET 6
Пакет "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 15.0.4797.1003" был восстановлен с помощью ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8", а не целевой платформы проекта "net6.0-windows7.0". Этот пакет может быть не полностью совместим с вашим проектом.

Comment: это всего-лишь предупреждение, а не ошибка

Comment: @aepot, да, но как только действие доходит до кода связанного с этой библиотекой, сразу выкидывает ошибку: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Не удается найти указанный файл."` Попробую поискать другие способы, чтобы ворд в rich отображать, потом отпишусь, спасибо.

Comment: Вообще вы можете без ворда обойтись, сохраните как RTF и загрузите в RTB прямо из файла.